# button click not responding

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

This is the demo code and when I add onClickListener in fill function it is not working and if i set any other property like background color it works fine.

```
private void fillHolder(FriendsHolder holder, final Friend friend) {
        if (friend == null)
            return;
        Iterator<Button> iViews = holder.interests.iterator();
        Iterator<String> iInterests = friend.getInterests().iterator();
        while (iViews.hasNext() && iInterests.hasNext()) {
            iViews.next().setText(iInterests.next());
        }
        Iterator<Button> iViewss = holder.interests.iterator();
        while (iViewss.hasNext()) {
            iViewss.next().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), friend.getNickname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        holder.infoPage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(friend.getBackground()));
        holder.nickName.setText(friend.getNickname());

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: @g2o Where ?, SO is not letting me edit the question.

Comment: Post it as a comment.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda it's too long to be a comment.

Comment: You should've created a new question and accepted an answer that was already here. The existing answers don't make any sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through `iViewss` (with double **S** in the end) and you're setting the listener to `iViews`(with single **S** in the end).

It's not the same object.

`iViews.next().setOnClickListener()` will throw a **NoSuchElementException** because there is not a next element.

Change your code like that:

```
private void fillHolder(FriendsHolder holder, final Friend friend) {
        if (friend == null)
            return;
        Iterator<Button> iViews = holder.interests.iterator();
        Iterator<String> iInterests = friend.getInterests().iterator();
        while (iViews.hasNext() && iInterests.hasNext()) {
            iViews.next().setText(iInterests.next());
        }
        while (iViews.hasNext()) {
            iViews.next().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), friend.getNickname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        holder.infoPage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(friend.getBackground()));
        holder.nickName.setText(friend.getNickname());

 }
```

**EDIT:**

You can also combine the two while-loops (as [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) suggestion):

```
private void fillHolder(FriendsHolder holder, final Friend friend) {

            if (friend == null)
                return;

            Iterator<Button> iViews = holder.interests.iterator();
            Iterator<String> iInterests = friend.getInterests().iterator();

            while (iViews.hasNext()) {

                Button button = iViews.next();

                if (iInterests.hasNext()) {
                    button.setText(iInterests.next());
                }

                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), friend.getNickname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            holder.infoPage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(friend.getBackground()));
            holder.nickName.setText(friend.getNickname());

     }
```

Comment: Could you not combine the while-loops to do `setText` and `setOnClickListener` in the same loop? Otherwise, it looks like OP was trying to reset the iterator for the `setOnClickListener`

Comment: So you just copy my answer? :) Okay

Comment: No, there is only one way to combine the two loops. Anyway, don't worry... i mentioned your name for the copyrights :D

Answer (score 0):

Along with the comments from the other answer, I think this code is more appropriate - it looks like you can combine the while-loops.

```
private void fillHolder(FriendsHolder holder, final Friend friend) {
    if (friend == null)
        return;
    Iterator<Button> iViews = holder.interests.iterator();
    Iterator<String> iInterests = friend.getInterests().iterator();
    while (iViews.hasNext()) {
        Button nextButton = iViews.next();
        if (iInterests.hasNext()) {
            nextButton.setText(iInterests.next());
        }
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), friend.getNickname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    holder.infoPage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(friend.getBackground()));
    holder.nickName.setText(friend.getNickname());

 }
```